# DatagridView Select last row

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have some trouble with setting the last row in my datagridview selected. I select the last row this way:

```
if (grid.Rows.Count > 0)
{
    try
    {
        grid.Rows[grid.Rows.Count - 1].Selected = true;
        grid.CurrentCell = grid.Rows[grid.Rows.Count - 1].Cells[1]
    }
    catch (IndexOutOfRangeException)
    { }
    catch (ArgumentOutOfRangeException)
    { }
}
```

When I execute this code I get an exception: `IndexOutOfRangeException occurred`: Index-1 does not have a value.

When I debug the `Rows`collection and the corresponding `Cells` collection I see both collections are filled. The index also exists of the Rows and Cells collection.

I have no clue what I am doing wrong here. Someone who can help me out here? Thnx

EDIT:

Here is the complete exception:

```
System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Index -1 does not have a value.
at System.Windows.Forms.CurrencyManager.get_Item(Int32 index)
at System.Windows.Forms.CurrencyManager.get_Current()
at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.DataGridViewDataConnection.OnRowEnter(DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.OnRowEnter(DataGridViewCell& dataGridViewCell, Int32 columnIndex, Int32 rowIndex, Boolean canCreateNewRow, Boolean validationFailureOccurred)
at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.SetCurrentCellAddressCore(Int32 columnIndex, Int32 rowIndex, Boolean setAnchorCellAddress, Boolean validateCurrentCell, Boolean throughMouseClick)
at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.set_CurrentCell(DataGridViewCell value)
```

Comment: Code seems fine. Have you tried debugging it? On what line of code are you getting the error?

Comment: Try a **Quick Watch** for `grid.Rows[grid.Rows.Count - 1].Cells[1]` and see what it returns.

Comment: @Aseem: the line is: `grid.CurrentCell = grid.Rows[grid.Rows.Count - 1].Cells[1] `

Comment: @KMan: Then I get the IndexOutOfRangeException. When I do grid.Rows[grid.Rows.Count - 1].Cells.Count I get 5

Answer (score 19):

Try:

```
dataGridView1.ClearSelection();//If you want

int nRowIndex = dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1;
int nColumnIndex = 3;

dataGridView1.Rows[nRowIndex].Selected = true;
dataGridView1.Rows[nRowIndex].Cells[nColumnIndex].Selected = true;

//In case if you want to scroll down as well.
dataGridView1.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex = nRowIndex;
```

**Gives following output**: (Last row, scrolled and selected)

[image]

Comment: @Martijn: I tested the code before posting. What exactly does not work?

Comment: On the line `dataGridView1.Rows[nRowIndex].Cells[nColumnIndex].Selected = true;
` I get the annoying Exception

Comment: @Martijn: Assuming the *exception* is same as in your question. Are you inserting any row manually? prior to binding?

Comment: @KMan: Before I select the last row I run this method: private void AddAppointmentsToGrid(IList<Appointment> appointments)
        {
            Collection<Appointment> apps = dgViewAfspraak.DataSource as Collection<Appointment>;
            dgViewAfspraak.DataSource = null;

            foreach (Appointment app in appointments)
            {
                apps.Add(app);
            }

            dgViewAfspraak.DataSource = apps;
        }

(Don't know how to show code in comments)

Comment: @Martijn: Can you restrict this method to add only one(or two) row(s) and test?

Comment: @KMan: take a look at my answer and the comments following - that might help point you folks in the right direction?

Comment: @KMan: When I insert one record I have the same exception

Comment: @Shaul: I don't know how to debug further on your suggestion

Comment: I did some research on the CurrencyManager and I found that that has something to do with databinding on the Form. Shaul told me (well, actually the Exception) that the Current property is empty. In my method (shown above in the method) sets the DataSource to null. Now I've changed that code and I don't use DataSource = null anymore. Now the code is working correct without an Exception.

Comment: ClearSelection - save my life ))

Comment: clearSelection is absolutely remarkable! but that if we're having multi selection enabled. otherwise everything is fine.

Answer (score 4):

I know this may be a little late but it may be of use to someone else.

Have you tried this :

`grid.Rows.Row[grid.Rows.Count -1].Selected = true;`

In my windows app I first used your code in my datagridview and I got the same exception.. and then it came to me at night when I was in my bed (I'm a newbie to programming).

If I write as : `Rows[Rows.count-1]` the first row is "0" and "0-1 = -1" so its out of range :)

Then when I changed my code to `Rows.Row[index]` it worked! :)

---

An alternative if you use c# 3.0 and higher: check out CellAddress();
;)

Sincerely

Answer (score 3):

Have you thought about using Linq for this?

```
    grid.Rows.OfType<DataGridViewRow>().Last().Selected = true;
    grid.CurrentCell = grid.Rows.OfType<DataGridViewRow>().Last().Cells.OfType<DataGridViewCell>().First(); // if first wanted
```

Comment: No I have not. But I don't have the Extension methods `Last()` and `First()`. I have the using System.Linq

Comment: Thanks. Tried your solution but I get the same Exception on this line: `grid.CurrentCell = grid.Rows.OfType<DataGridViewRow>().Last().Cells.OfType<DataGridViewCell>().Last();`

Comment: it doesn't make sense to get IndexOutOfRangeException on code that does not use index property at all. Sure it's the same exception?

Answer (score 1):

Your 'catch' block for IndexOutOfRangeException is empty, and will not display any error at all.

Either your question is not exact, or the exception is being thrown somewhere else.

**EDIT:** Having looked through your call stack that you added, I can see that the error is, indeed, **not** being thrown here, but rather in the `CurrencyManager` class's `Current`/`Item` properties, which is ultimately being triggered by the call to the `CurrentCell` setter.

Bottom line: the problem is not in this code; the exception is being thrown by some other piece of code triggered by your setting the current cell.

Comment: It does throw an excetpion in debug mode. The code stops running and VS is highlighting. But that is not the point. The point is, WHY is the exception thrown?

Comment: I would use the "Immediate" window to confirm the value of grid.Rows.Count, then try accessing grid.Rows[0] or whatever number using an integer literal, just to make sure.  I suspect the code here is not an exact copy of the code that's causing the exception, and somewhere in between that and what you *think* your code is doing lies the error.

Comment: In the immediate window I have rows and cells in the collections

Comment: EDIT: This DID NOT FIX MY PROBLEM! I still have the same Exception. I still have no idea what goes wrong. I only have these event handlers: `CellContentDoubleClick`and `CellDoubleClick`

Comment: @Martijn - What did you find in the CurrencyManager form?  The exception is originating there, in those methods I mentioned in my answer.  Somewhere in the `Current` property you're making reference to the Item indexer property, with an index of -1, which obviously doesn't exist.

Comment: To answer your question in the edit: I haven't create my own form in that namespace. I do use a control which is based on the windows datagrid (DevComponents' DotNetBar DataGridViewX). How can I check the CurrencyManager form?

Comment: Ah, my mistake, apparently there *is* a CurrencyManager class in System.Windows.Forms (shoulda googled before opening my big mouth!) http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.currencymanager.aspx  I've never seen it before or worked with it - but you clearly are, somewhere in your datagrid.  That's about all I can tell you for now; hopefully I've pointed you more or less in the right direction.  Good luck!

Comment: So you think I have to look at the CurrencyManager from the Windows Form?

Answer (score 1):

```
dataGridView1.Rows[dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1].Selected = true;
```

Answer (score 0):

Eventually the last row is empty because it's the empty row with which the user can add a new row. This row cannot be selected.
Have you tried grid.Rows.Count - 2? As an alternative, you can set AllowUserToAddRows to false.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid the IndexOutOfRangeException make sure only to select a visible row.
I suggest:

```
// Find last visible row
DataGridViewRow row = dataGridView1.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>().Where(r => r.Visible).Last(); 
// scroll to last row if necessary
dataGridView1.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex = dataGridView1.Rows.IndexOf(row);
// select row
row.Selected = true;
```

Answer (score 0):

It's very easy. use:
    dataGridView.CurrentCell=dataGridView[ColumnIndex, RowIndex];
    dataGridView[X,y]...
instead of
    dataGridView[Y, X]...