# DataGridView scroll to last row while WrapMode true

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

In my **winforms .NET 4** application, I have to keep adding new rows at the bottom of `DataGridView`. The row contains two columns and I have to:

1. Wrap/break lines for long strings inside cells. For that I did

   `myDGV.DefaultCellStyle.WrapMode = true;`
2. Scroll to the bottom to show the last added row and if needed show scroll bar too. So I did

   `myDGV.ScrollBars = ScrollBars.Both;
    myDGV.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex = lastRow.Index;`

and binding data to `myDGV` via DataSource.

The wrap mode is working perfectly, but if some rows have different heights, because of the wrap mode, the scrolling has two issues:

- The scroll bar is not scrolling to the bottom. Some times stays in the middle. So I have to go select one row and do manual scrolling to see the last row.
- The manual scrolling is not smooth like if all rows have the same height. I think the scroll bar is trying to scroll by row not by pixel. If I have "short" rows between "tall" ones, the former ones will be skipped while scrolling.

Is there a way to fix these two issues? Should I consider another winforms control?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?:

FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex:
[link to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3810722/c-sharp-datagridview-select-last-row)

Or Using devexpress control, you can make this by simple way...

Hope I help you

---

I read well now your answer. I think you have problem with lastRow.index , have you tried this?: dataGridView1.ClearSelection();//If you want

int nRowIndex = dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1;
int nColumnIndex = 3;

dataGridView1.Rows[nRowIndex].Selected = true;
dataGridView1.Rows[nRowIndex].Cells[nColumnIndex].Selected = true;

//In case if you want to scroll down as well.
dataGridView1.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex = nRowIndex;

source:

[C# DatagridView Select last row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3810722/c-sharp-datagridview-select-last-row)